# Text is not crisp when set on top of HTML 5 video

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have a form sitting on top of an HTML5 video (the video is purely for decoration). When the video renders, the text becomes extremely blurry. When I delete the video node using Chrome Dev Tools, the text because nice and clean again.

See the two screenshots.

What would be causing this rendering issue? I'm not even sure what code to include because I don't even know where to begin debugging this

[image: Fuzzy Form]

[image: Crisp Text]

Comment: have you tried different browers/versions/os?

Comment: It is really hard to tell your images apart... I'm assuming the top one is more blurry?

Comment: @alexpmil you are correct -- the text is more blurry in the top one. I didn't realize Stackoverflow wouldn't upload them at full size.

Comment: @RonniSkansing Yes, it appears to be this way in both Chrome and safari.

Comment: Can you share a link?

Comment: this is a working beta site, but it is beta.life.edu

Comment: Chrome and Safari are based off WebKit and I've seen this happen just with overlaying text on certain elements. Check IE and Firefox as they render nice and sharp. Not sure how'd you'd get around it TBH.

Comment: @papa -- thanks, thats part of what I've come to realize.

Comment: @idealbrandon you should try not just picking out the words you like in my question and try MORE browsers, different versions, different  operating systems? Just trying the two browsers you got there means nothing.

Comment: @RonniSkansing I apologize for not being clear. I have tested multiple browsers, OSes, and browser versions. It appears this way in Safari and Chrome, but not in other browsers that I have tested.

Answer (score 0):

One method to try: separate the text container from the video/masthead container so they're siblings/not nested.

```
<div id="masthead">
    <video></video>
</div>
<div id="masthead-intro">
    Text
</div>
```